# Why some characters are displaying in my assembly code?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I wrote a simple *Print String* in assembly (in 16 bit) but after running the .EXE code it displays my String and alot of characters that I don't know where they come from ....

```
stk segment 
    dw 32 dup(0)
stk ends


dts segment 
msg db "hello world"
dts ends

cds segment 
    assume ss:stk , cs:cds , ds:dts
    main proc far

        mov ax,seg dts
        mov ds,ax
        mov dx,offset msg
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h 
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21 
        main endp
cds ends 
end main
```

Comment: The string is not properly terminated, use "hello world$"

Comment: It's a good idea to read a detailed description of the functions you are using. Ralf Brown's [interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) is a famous resource.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked DOS to print the string that you've defined using

```
msg db "hello world"
```

You've provided DOS with the start of this string (`mov dx,offset msg`) but *DOS can't know where the string ends*. That's why **you** need to terminate your string with a dollar character ($). DOS then knows this is the end of the string. DOS will not display the `$` itself.

```
msg db "hello world$"
```

Or if you prefer for clarity:

```
msg db "hello world", "$"
```

As an improvement you could also print a newline. Change the definition into:

```
msg db "hello world", 13, 10, "$"
```

The ASCII code 13 is carriage return which brings the cursor to the left edge of the screen, and the ASCII code 10 is linefeed which moves the cursor 1 line down on the screen.
The dollar character ($) again is the last item of the string.

---

> ```
> mov ah,4ch
> int 21
> ```

Now this is probably just a typo, but it's an important one. You forgot the hexadecimal suffix (h).

```
mov ax,4C00h
int 21h
```